# arduino print qrcode via thermal printer

Tags: arduino

I am using qrcode library
https://github.com/ricmoo/QRCode

for generating QR code at runtime

but i can not print it using Adafruit Thermal Printer

which uses method `printer.printBitmap(x,y,qrdata)`

now my problem is how to convert the qrcode generated from qrcode library to

`static const uint8_t PROGMEM adaqrcode_data[] = {
  0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, .....`

edit :

i tried the code

```
QRCode qrcode;
int  buffsize = qrcode_getBufferSize(10);
uint8_t *qrcodeBytes= malloc(buffsize);
qrcode_initText(&qrcode, qrcodeBytes, 10, ECC_LOW, "Test");
const uint8_t myB[qrcode.size]={qrcode.modules};
printer.printBitmap(50,50,myB,false);
```

qrcode.modules is the bytes of qrcode

it prints as shown in picture attached ... and its not qrcode !

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZZXt.png)

Comment: Where did you get that the size of the QR code is 50? How long is `qrcode.modules`?

Comment: 50,50 is the width and height of image

qrcode.size is the size of qrcode.modules bytes array

Comment: In that case, don't you have 50x50=2500 values? if qrcode.size=50 you did not allocate enough space for myB. Bitmap are huge, that is why Adafruit usually store them in progspace.

Comment: i think the main problem is how to get thermal printer format from qrcode outeput


the QRCode https://github.com/ricmoo/QRCode produces array of bytes but how o convert them to thermal printer image format so i can print it using  Adafruit Thermal Library.